# Can I power 3.5" SATA disk via a double USB adapter?

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, sata, sata-to-usb

I want to recover data from a Samsung HD501LJ 3.5" SATA disk.

https://www.hdsentinel.com/storageinfo_details.php?lang=en&model=SAMSUNG%20HD501LJ

I have no more working desktop to connect it to.

I have a working USB adapter enclosure for a 2.5" SATA drive. It has 2 USB connectors, one for power, one for data.

Is it safe to connect the 3.5" Samsung drive to the USB adapter? I'm confused about the different voltages on SATA.
[image]

Similar question: [How to power a 3.5in drive from a laptop?](https://superuser.com/questions/297149/how-to-power-a-3-5in-drive-from-a-laptop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick answer: no.

The 3.5" hdd needs +12V rail to be powered for it to work. The USB port does not provide that. Thus, if the adapter does not have a 5V to 12V booster, which I highly doubt as 2.5" disks do not use 12V, it will simply not power on. Also, the spin-up current of 3.5" hdd:s is such that it would bring the USB port to its knees unless the adapter had some massive on-board capacitors or such behind the boost converter, which it clearly does not.

Longer answer: sort of.

Technically you can. But you have to modify the adapter by adding external wires for the +12V rail. I did this with a König adapter (CSU2HDE25S100), partly just for fun and partly because the adapter was dirt cheap and breaking it was not a real concern. Also, I have some retired 1 TB hdd lying around which still works and wanted to test if I could somehow use it for something.
So, I hand-soldered wires to the adapter PCB, +12V to pins 13 & 15 and GND to the pins 10 & 12 of the SATA power connector. The 12V pins were not initially connected to anything on the adapter, so adding the power was quite easy.
After the modification and feeding 12V to the wires by an external (floating) laboratory power supply, the HDD would start normally when connected to the adapter and I can now use it as normal USB drive in Windows and it seems to work normally.
It is rather inconvenient to use, but I use it for offline back-ups of the computer file system every once in a while, so it is not that bad.

I would only recommend this mod if you have the tools and knowledge and are not afraid of losing the data, the HDD or the adapter (or even your PC:s USB interface as accidentally feeding +12V to it by mis-soldered wires might cause it to give up the ghost).

-Tatu

Answer (score 3):

You should not attempt to do that.

First of all, 3.5" drives use 12V in addition to 5V, which your case most likely can't provide.

But more importantly: If you want to recover data, the one thing you do NOT want ist to put your disk into any non-optimal working conditions. Not 100% clean and sufficient power might keep your disk sort of working but put an enormous strain on the drives motor speed controller. It might also be "just not enough" with your drive restarting, again making your recovery job harder and more risky.

A 3.5" case (or a "HDD docking station") is a few $/€ on e-Bay and will come with a dedicated power supply.

Comment: In a pinch (edge case scenario) I've found SATA+idr to USB converters which come with an additional power supply that puts out 5 and 12 volts. If you handle the grounding correctly (I suspect the drives will do it, otherwise link the 2 black power cables to SATA ground this could work. Not a great or safe solution, but better then trying to power it off a Y connector.

Answer (score -2):

Yes. It is possible.
Connect the data usb cable to 12 volt supply.
Cut it identify + and - and connect it to 12 volt power supply.

Comment: That sounds like the worst idea ever. It is virtually guaranteed to fry the USB-SATA electronics and it’s highly likely to fry the hard disk’s electronics, too.